# How to get the user activity details in Huawei AppGallery Operation analysis page?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, appgallery-connect

How to see the data from Huawei AppGallery Operation analysis such as,

1. The length of time users stay in the app
2. The daily retention rate of users

Is there any way to get these data? Anyone please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For viewing the length of time the user stays in the app and the data required for operations such for operations such as the user's daily retention rate, please follow below steps

1. Click Add filter and set the filter criteria. For details, please refer to Adding a Filter.
   [image]
2. Select a time segment as required.

[image]

3. View the report generated, which illustrates the trend in the new user retention rate and daily details through a graph and a table. Click Day, Week, or Month to switch the time dimension.
   [image]

4. Save users retained for a specified period as an audience.

For more information please find below link :

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/retention-analysis-new-0000001078671792